How do I get the result where the latest record in one-to-many relationship matches a given condition in graphQL Hasura?
So, I'm new to GraphQL and I'm trying to fetch the profiles whose latest billing (created_at) has a next_at value matching the one I input.
This is my attempt but it is incorrect since the filtering is applied to all billings not the latest one:
profiles(where: { billing: { status: { _eq: "finished" }, invoice_id: { _is_null: false }, next_at: { _gte: $minNextAt, _lte: $maxNextAt } } }) {
        id
        user {
            id
            email
            displayName,
        }
        billing(order_by: { created_at: desc }, limit: 1) {
            id
            package_name
        }
    }

